# How to find current template in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Is there any function to find current templates?

```
<template name="Login">
   <h1>{{template}}</h1> //Should display Login
</template>
```

or

```
<template name="Login">
   <h1>{{showtemplate}}</h1>
</template>
```

Helperjs:

```
showtemplate: function(){
   return Template;
}
```

Comment: very close! `return Template.instance();` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the name of the template, you can get it like this:

```
showtemplate: function(){
  return Template.instance().view.name;
}
```

This will return the string "Template.yourTemplateName"